# large wasm size for polkadot 0.9.17

Tags: wasm

We have recently upgraded our runtime to polkadot 0.9.17. We noticed the wasm runtime seems too large i.e. 5.3 MB which exceeds the limit.

Is there a way or best approach to reduce the wasm size?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You should use the compressed runtime artefact generated by the build.

For instance in the case of Kusama it is `kusama_runtime-v9170.compact.compressed.wasm` (note the `*.compressed.wasm`) as per the [assets on the release](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.17-rc4).

Comment: Thank you Jaco!

Comment: I'm guessing the normal runtime.wasm and runtime.compact.wasm are just intemediate build files at this point? (Since compression support is there and there doesn't seem a reason to use them at all anymore)

Comment: you can use `subwasm compress` and `subwasm decompress` to compress and decompress runtimes ( https://github.com/chevdor/subwasm )